# Insert "Selected Users" into another table

Tags: php, html, mysql

Okay I am having all kinds of problems trying to figure the way to script this.

What I want to do is have a list of people displayed from a mysql database. 
Once list is generated I would like to have a checkbox next to each person.

Now here is the tricky part (at least for me), for each person checked I would like to enter it into only 1 column in another table in the database. We will call it "rsvp" I for the life of me cannot figure this out.

Basically I would need to enter user id's from the checkbox ex these are id's checked "1,4,5,6,8". Now I would need to enter that into a database table "rsvp" and then be able to go back and modify that same entry with the checkboxes already selected.

I think I am way over thinking this and it is actually a very simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

You should

1) Get the result set from the database

2) Get an array of selected members

3) Iterate of the actual dataset and keep generating check boxes, if id matches the selected id, generate the check box as checked.

4) On submitting the form, clear old entries and re-insert whatsoever has been selected.

```
  <form>
  <?php
  $resultSet = getAllTheUsers here ////
  $arrayOfSelectedUsers= getAlreadySelectedUsers();

 //      keep the array as "id"=>'User name'

  while(result is not empty){
    if(array_key_exists('bar', $foo)) 
       echo "<checkbox value=$result['userId'] checked='checked' name='rsvp' />";
   else
      echo "<checkbox value=$result['userId']  name='rsvp' />";
  }
  ?>
  <input type='submit' />
  </form>
```

This should give you an idea. Once the form is submitted, get all the values, delete the existing entries from the database and re-insert what so ever has been selected again.